# How to combine multiple transitions with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, transition

I would like to create an effect using CSS3 transitions. A div should change its width and background-color on mouseover. Then on mouseout it should wait 2 seconds and then go back to its normal width and background color. What I did is add a class `hoverclass` via jQuery on mouseover and remove it on mouseout. Check out the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MMKnx/).

I have two problems with this. First thing is that browsers will interpret the fiddle differently. In Chrome everything works fine, on mouseover the div will change its width immediately, then waits 2 sec on mouseout and goes back to normal size. In Firefox however, the newly added hoverclass will be directly used as the new transition rule. So what happens is that on mouseover the animation will start after 2 seconds. Then on mouseout the class will be removed and what happens is that Firefox will take the transition rule from `#test` so the div will directly go back to its normal size without delay.

Second thing I noticed is that when I try to animate two properties, background-color and width when using a new transition rule only for the width (like in hoverclass) it will overwrite the one for the background-color. Does that mean I have to write ALL the transition properties I used in `#test` in the hoverclass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put the `2s` on the wrong css selector.  You really don't need to add an additional class.  So you can get rid of jQuery.  You can just use the :hover transition.  http://jsfiddle.net/MMKnx/1/

```
#test
{
    width:100px;
    height:500px;
    background-color:#06F;
    -webkit-transition: background-color .5s ease-in-out,width .5s ease 2s;
    -moz-transition: background-color .5s ease-in-out,width .5s ease 2s;
    -o-transition: background-color .5s ease-in-out,width .5s ease 2s;
    transition: background-color .5s ease-in-out,width .5s ease 2s;
}
#test:hover
{
    -webkit-transition: width .75s ease;
    -moz-transition: width .75s ease;
    -o-transition: width .75s ease;
    transition: width .75s ease;
}
#test:hover
{
    background-color:#96C;
    width:800px;
}
```

Comment: Ok you are right. In this example it would work without. But if for example I wanted to change the width on mouseover, then wait 2 seconds, then change the width to 300px and then wait again 2 seconds before changing it to 200 px, I would need to add a class. How would I do it in that case?

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/MMKnx/2/  unhovering uses the CSS, then javascript times out after 4 seconds of unhovering causing the final transition.